# Overloading Operators - C++

Tags: c++, operators, overload

I was experimenting with new overloaded operators, I have created one void operator and another one that returns something when it's called:

```
#include <iostream>

struct chichachicha{
    int operator()(){
        return 25;
    };
};

struct boomboom{
    void operator()() {
        std::cout << "Hi folks!" << std::endl;
    };
};

int main(){
    chichachicha objC;
    int f = objC();
    std::cout << f << std::endl;
    boomboom objB;
    objB();
    return(0);
}
```

Is this the best way to write a code that does that?

How can I write an operator that can be called from anywhere in the code without instantiating the associated struct, that returns `void`/nothing and only prints a string of text? I'm not considering static methods, just operators.

Comment: The whole point of operator is to operate on something. If you don't want something, you don't want an operator. Probably a free function (the whole "everything should be in a class" mentality is alien to C++; things should be in namespaces).

Comment: The question sounds a bit like "I have a hammer, now how do I screw in this screw with it". Could you put in more detail about what you want to achieve without presuming that it should involve operator()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Despite "*I'm not considering static methods, just operators*", the statement immediately before it suggests you are asking for a static `operator()`. If this were possible, the [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) would be much more vexing!

Upon further inspection, it reads like you are basically in the market for a static function. The whole purpose of `operator()` is to make a functor. If you want a polymorphic version of `operator()`, I'm afraid you'll have to instantiate something somewhere.

Comment: i was experimenting with namespaces, but apparently i can't do more than what i can do in the main.

Comment: Why a _static_ function? A simple free function would do that, too.

Comment: I use "static" and "free" interchangeably. Though `static` is often used to refer to an unbound function member of a class, the compiler treats them the same way.